# 1D CNN Model using CSV File

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am looking at using mass spectrometry data to build a CNN model. I have 5 different classes with 2300 readings for each dataset. I do need some help to check if what I am doing is correct and if it's in the right direction! I have attached an image on how the data looks like on excel. [excel data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6Zot.png] Some questions are added as comments in the code, if anyone can help to explain!

Importing libraries and dataset

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = pd.read_csv('CAP.data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
```

Split training and testing set

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv1D
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Conv1D, Dropout, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling1D, LeakyReLU

ms_input_shape = (2300,3) #Could someone suggest how I should set the input shape to be?

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=6, kernel_size=21, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape= ms_input_shape,kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()))
model.add(BatchNormalization()) #what is the purpose of this!
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(120, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(84))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

Results:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d (Conv1D)             (None, 2300, 6)           384       
                                                                 
 batch_normalization (BatchN  (None, 2300, 6)          24        
 ormalization)                                                   
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D  (None, 1150, 6)          0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv1d_1 (Conv1D)           (None, 1150, 16)          496       
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_1 (Batc  (None, 1150, 16)         64        
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 575, 16)          0         
 1D)                                                             
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 9200)              0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 120)               1104120   
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 84)                10164     
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 425       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,115,677
Trainable params: 1,115,633
Non-trainable params: 44
```

Why there are 44 non-trainable parameters?

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])


callbacks_list = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath='best_model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5',
        monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True),
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='acc', patience=1)]

BATCH_SIZE = 32 #I am not sure what batch size should I set for my case?
EPOCHS = 20

history = model.fit(X_train,
                    y_train,
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs=EPOCHS,
                    callbacks=callbacks_list,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    verbose=1)
```

And I got this error for running history

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_2" (type Sequential).
Input 0 of layer "conv1d_4" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 2300)
Call arguments received:• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 2300), dtype=float32) • training=True • mask=None
```

Could someone advise?

Answer (score 0):

Conv1D expects input of shape 3+D tensor with shape: `batch_shape + (steps, input_dim)`

You need add extra dimension to your input shape.

**Working sample code**

```
#from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten, Conv1D, Dropout, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling1D, LeakyReLU
import numpy as np

ms_input_shape = (10,2300,3) #Could someone suggest how I should set the input shape to be?
X_train = np.random.random((10,2300,3))
y_train = np.random.random((10, 5))

model = keras.models.Sequential()
#model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer())
model.add(Conv1D(filters=6, kernel_size=21, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu',input_shape= ms_input_shape[1:],kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.he_normal()))
model.add(BatchNormalization()) #what is the purpose of this!
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='same'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(120, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(84))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
```

**Output**

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv1d_5 (Conv1D)           (None, 2300, 6)           384       
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_5 (Batc  (None, 2300, 6)          24        
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d_3 (MaxPooling  (None, 1150, 6)          0         
 1D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv1d_6 (Conv1D)           (None, 1150, 16)          496       
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_6 (Batc  (None, 1150, 16)         64        
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 max_pooling1d_4 (MaxPooling  (None, 575, 16)          0         
 1D)                                                             
                                                                 
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         (None, 9200)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 120)               1104120   
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 84)                10164     
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 425       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 1,115,677
Trainable params: 1,115,633
Non-trainable params: 44
___________________________
```

**Model Training**

```
import tensorflow as tf
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])


callbacks_list = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath='best_model.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5',
        monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True),
    keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='acc', patience=1)]

BATCH_SIZE = 32 #I am not sure what batch size should I set for my case?
EPOCHS = 20

history = model.fit(X_train,
                    y_train,
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs=EPOCHS,
                    callbacks=callbacks_list,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    verbose=1)
```

**Output**

```
Epoch 1/20
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 5.9319 - acc: 0.1250 - val_loss: 6.6557 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 2/20
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 53ms/step - loss: 16.2454 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 6.8568 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/20
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 45ms/step - loss: 14.0361 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 6.9775 - val_acc: 1.0000
```